# Is $1-\sqrt{-5}$ irreducible in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt {-5}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A:=\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-5}]$, suppose that we want to know if $1-\sqrt {-5}$ is either irreducible or invertible. Is a valid strategy to write $A$ as $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+5)$, and check if the ideal $(x^2+5,1-x)$ is, respectively, either prime or not proper? I'd say $1-\sqrt {-5}$ is neither prime nor invertible because $\mathbb Z[x]/(1-x,x^2+5)\cong \mathbb Z/(6)$. For example if $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-2}]$ and $a:=1-\sqrt {-2}$, we'd have $\mathbb Z[x]/(1-x,x^2+2)\cong \mathbb Z/(3)$, and, if $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {0}]$ and $b:=1-\sqrt {0}$, we'd have $\mathbb Z[x]/(1-x,x^2)\cong 0$, meaning that $a$ is irreducible and $b$  invertible. Is this ok? Or am I committing any mistake?

Comment: @markvs because (I can be wrong) $\mathbb Z[x]/(1-x,x^2+5)\cong \mathbb Z[1]/(1+5)\cong \mathbb Z/(6)$

Comment: You've deduced it is not prime, but that doesn't imply it is not irreducible because irreducibles needn't be prime in non-UFDs

Comment: I'm just putting $x=1$ because $1-x=0$ why is it wrong?

Comment: As Bill Dubuque points out, you correctly show that it is not prime, but that does not show that it is not irreducible. To show that it is irreducible, do you know about the norm function $N \colon \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] \to \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Thanks for the correction concerning the irreducibility, usually in the course I encounter polynomials over fields or at least UFD so I didn't mean to  see more details about irreducibillity.

Comment: @markvs because $f:\mathbb Z[x]\to \mathbb Z$ defined by $1\mapsto 1, x\mapsto 1$ is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $1-x$, so $\mathbb Z[x]/(1-x)\cong \mathbb Z$ and the isomorphism associates $x$ to $1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1 - \sqrt{-5}$ is indeed irreducible.

Consider the function $f : \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] \to \mathbb{Z}_+$ defined by $f(a + b \sqrt{-5}) = a^2 + 5 b^2$. Note that this function has the property that $f(a) f(b) = f(ab)$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and that $f(1) = 1$. Then $f$ is a monoid homomorphism between the multiplicative monoids of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_+$.

Further note that $f(x) = 1$ if and only if $x = \pm 1$. So if $f(x) = 1$, then $x$ is a unit. And of course the converse is also true, since the only invertible element of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ is 1, so if $x$ is a unit then $f(x) = 1$.

Now $f(1 - \sqrt{-5}) = 6$.

Suppose that we can write $1 - \sqrt{-5} = xy$ with neither $a$ nor $b$ a unit. Then $f(x) f(y) = 6$. Since neither $x$ nor $y$ is a unit, neither $f(x)$ nor $f(y)$ is 1, so the only option is (without loss of generality) $f(x) = 2$ and $f(y) = 3$.

Write $x = a + b \sqrt{-5}$. Then $f(x) = 2 = a^2 + 5 b^2$.

Clearly, we must have $b = 0$, since for $b \neq 0$, we have $a + 5b^2 \geq 5b^2 \geq 5 > 2$. Then $a^2 = 2$. But 2 is not the square of an integer. Contradiction.

You are correct that $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ is not prime. This is possible because $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a UFD, so not all irreducibles have to be prime.